# What's the difference between 赤ん坊　and 赤ちゃん

Tags: word-choice, usage, nuances

Are both words interchangeable? Rikai-chan defines them both as "baby, infant". So what would be the difference?

Answer (score 9):

In many contexts they are interchangeable, but strictly speaking 赤ん坊 is the actual word for baby, and 赤ちゃん is like a cute, pet name derived from it.

Also, 赤ん坊 is the spoken (colloquial) form - see sawa's comment for versions that may be more appropriate for formal writing.

Comment: Perhaps another point is that 赤ちゃん is more common in colloquial and common usage,  I think.

Comment: 赤子 is archaic. You do not use it any more. Formal ways of saying it are 新生児, 乳児, 幼児, or 乳幼児, which cover different ages.